# Automatically Detect New entry and create another new row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have one google spreadsheet with two sheets that have same number of rows.

What I want to do:
When a new entry is written after the last row of **Sheet1**, it will automatically copy the last row of **Sheet2** and paste it after that. (The new row will be in the last row after this, and both sheets will have same row again)

Since I don't use google script too much, I don't know how to accomplish it. Which functions or formula shall I use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When row z is added, the copy of v will be added after v.

Comment: Exactly. V is made of formulas, so the data of copies of v is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `onEdit()` function, and the `getLastRow()` method, and `copyTo()`

```
function onEdit(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  // This logs the value in the very last cell of this sheet
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var lastCell = sheet.getRange(lastRow, lastColumn);
  Logger.log(lastCell.getValue());

  var lastRowAndCol = lastRow + ":" + lastRow;
  var newRowOnEnd = (lastRow+1) + ":" + (lastRow+1);

  Logger.log('lastRowAndCol: ' + lastRowAndCol);
  Logger.log('newRowOnEnd: ' + newRowOnEnd);

  sheet.getRange(lastRowAndCol).copyTo(sheet.getRange(newRowOnEnd));
};
```

[Google Documentation - onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit)

[Google Documentation - getLastRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getLastRow())

[copyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,Object))

Comment: Glad you got it working.  I did edit the answer and make some changes with some text formulas to get the cell addresses.